# Bing Search not getting my Title & Description tags in the search results using React JS (data-rh="true")

Tags: dataframe, attributes, using, react-helmet, helmet.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCH0L.png)

The Bing Search results are not showing the title & Description in SERP as I am looking to resolve this issue with my Deve. personal and still did not figure it out the issue.

Using React Helmet to dynamically manage the title and description tags of our web pages' server-side rendering.

using (data-rh="true")

The common issue with React Helmet is that it does not override the default title and description tags that are in the index.html file. This can cause our web pages to show the wrong title and description in the search results. To fix this, we add the data-rh or data-react-helmet attribute to the tags in our index.html file that we want to override with React Helmet.